# how to run tsk_recover from python

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code in python where "fullpathimage" has a full path to the image directory and "outdir" has a full path to output directory. Both variables show correct information inside. But I'm still getting this error. Also both files and directories exist. And tsk_recover is installed on the system:

```
def ExplodeIMAGE(self, fullpathimage, outdir):
    # Show how command should execute
    print __file__ + ' -d ' + fullpathimage,' -o ' +  outdir + '\n'


    # use tsk_recover to extract files from images
    TSKrecover= subprocess.Popen(['tsk_recover ', ' -e ',fullpathimage, outdir], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    TSKrecover,TSKrecovererror = TSKrecover.communicate()
    print TSKrecover


run.ExplodeIMAGE(fullpathimage, outdir)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
    ./image.py -d /tools/iso/File1.001 -o /tools/tmp
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./image.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "./image.py", line 74, in main
    run.ExplodeIMAGE(fullpathimage, outdir)
  File "./image.py", line 23, in ExplodeIMAGE
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: the message is clear, "No such file or directory"

Comment: But all the files and directories exist in their respective locations....